# How to prevent modal closing when I clicked outside with tailwindcss

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I write a code that it shows a modal. And it is from the tailwind css homepage.
It works fine but, It seems that When I clicked the outside of the modal, it closes. So I search how to prevent click and close event.

And I found some stuffs, but it's not working.

`https://tailwindcss.com/docs/pointer-events` said that if I use pointer-event-none it will ignore pointer events but its not working.

And I also found this site `https://tailwind-elements.com/docs/standard/components/modal/`

it said when I set backdrop to static it will not close when I click outside of it. but still not works.

Is there any classes in tailwindcss to solve this problem?

```
import { Fragment, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Dialog, Transition } from "@headlessui/react";
import { ExclamationTriangleIcon } from "@heroicons/react/24/outline";

export default function AuthModal() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    let authInformation = localStorage.getItem("authInformation");
    console.log(`authInformation: ${authInformation}`);
    if (authInformation) {
      setOpen(false);
    } else {
      setOpen(true);
    }
  }, []);

  const cancelButtonRef = useRef(null);

  return (
    <Transition.Root show={open} as={Fragment}>
      <Dialog
        as="div"
        className="relative z-10"
        initialFocus={cancelButtonRef}
        onClose={setOpen}
      >
        <Transition.Child
          as={Fragment}
          enter="ease-out duration-300"
          enterFrom="opacity-0"
          enterTo="opacity-100"
          leave="ease-in duration-200"
          leaveFrom="opacity-100"
          leaveTo="opacity-0"
        >
          <div className="fixed inset-0 bg-gray-500 bg-opacity-75 transition-opacity" />
        </Transition.Child>

        <div className="fixed inset-0 z-10 overflow-y-auto">
          <div className="flex min-h-full items-end justify-center p-4 text-center sm:items-center sm:p-0">
            <Transition.Child
              as={Fragment}
              enter="ease-out duration-300"
              enterFrom="opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95"
              enterTo="opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100"
              leave="ease-in duration-200"
              leaveFrom="opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100"
              leaveTo="opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95"
            >
              <Dialog.Panel className="relative transform overflow-hidden rounded-lg bg-white text-left shadow-xl transition-all sm:my-8 sm:w-full sm:max-w-lg">
                <div className="bg-white px-4 pt-5 pb-4 sm:p-6 sm:pb-4">
                  <div className="sm:flex sm:items-start">
                    <div className="mx-auto flex h-12 w-12 flex-shrink-0 items-center justify-center rounded-full bg-red-100 sm:mx-0 sm:h-10 sm:w-10">
                      <ExclamationTriangleIcon
                        className="h-6 w-6 text-red-600"
                        aria-hidden="true"
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div className="mt-3 text-center sm:mt-0 sm:ml-4 sm:text-left">
                      <Dialog.Title
                        as="h3"
                        className="text-lg font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900"
                      >
                        No user information!
                      </Dialog.Title>
                      <div className="mt-2">
                        <p className="text-sm text-gray-500">
                          Please Enter your UserID
                        </p>
                        <input
                          className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 mt-2 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                          id="userId"
                          type="text"
                          placeholder="UserId"
                        />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="bg-gray-50 px-4 py-3 sm:flex sm:flex-row-reverse sm:px-6">
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="inline-flex w-full justify-center rounded-md border border-transparent bg-blue-600 px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-500 focus:ring-offset-2 sm:ml-3 sm:w-auto sm:text-sm"
                    onClick={() => setOpen(false)}
                  >
                    Deactivate
                  </button>
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="mt-3 inline-flex w-full justify-center rounded-md border border-gray-300 bg-white px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-700 shadow-sm hover:bg-gray-50 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:ring-offset-2 sm:mt-0 sm:ml-3 sm:w-auto sm:text-sm"
                    onClick={() => setOpen(true)}
                    ref={cancelButtonRef}
                  >
                    Cancel
                  </button>
                </div>
              </Dialog.Panel>
            </Transition.Child>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Dialog>
    </Transition.Root>
  );
}
```

Comment: ```onClose={setOpen}``` remove this from the <Dialog> and that will not close modal on outside click